Can a ground connection for a 230VAC device go to a 0V of a 24VDC circuit?
So, here is the situation: We are designing a small oven made out of aluminum. For it we plan to use a power adapter from 230VAC to 24VDC. The problem is that the temperature controller we have outputs 230VAC. Because of time constraints we can not buy another temperature controller, so we have to go with what we have.
Since the output of the controller is 230VAC, the aluminum oven has to be connected to ground to avoid getting shocked if the phase wire feeding the heating element touches the metal oven.
My question is, can I ground connect the oven to the 0V output of the 24 VDC power source?
Here you find a small sketch I did of the wiring I am thinking about:


Commonly done. The power supply might do it already.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I think this is what you are trying to describe.
Connecting the 0V to the oven chassis is fine. Just make sure that the oven still has its original direct connection to the mains earth (and doesn't daisy chain through your PSU).
